# MySQL - Remote connections requesting caching_sha2_password after switching to mysql_native_password

Tags: php, mysql, remote-access

I had trouble connecting to MySQL 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 in localhost because Node's MySQL library has yet to implement `caching_sha2_password`, so I modified the user with the following query in order to switch to the old `mysql_native_password` algorithm.

```
ALTER USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypass';
```

Then I wanted to connect remotely, so I created a new `test_remote` user identified with `mysql_native_password`, as the list of users shows.

```
+------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| User             | plugin                | authentication_string                                                  |
+------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| test             | mysql_native_password | *88F9....................................                              |
| test_remote      | mysql_native_password | *88F9....................................                              |
+------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The problem is that I can correctly connect in localhost, but remote connections are still requesting `caching_sha2_password`. Specifically, I tried connecting with PHP v7.1.7 using the following code:

```
<?php
$ms = new mysqli("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "test_remote", "mypass", "mydb);
if($ms->connect_error) {
  echo $ms->connect_error;
}
```

Which results in:

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in C:\xampp\htdocs\thrive-web\test.php on line 2

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in C:\xampp\htdocs\thrive-web\test.php on line 2
The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

I looked for other questions and resources but they all say to change the password plugin, which I already did, so I'm clueless at the moment.
Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks!

Comment: PHP 7.1.7 doesn't support caching_sha2_password. It was only added in PHP 7.4

Comment: @Dharman Indeed, that's why I set `mysql_native_password` as plugin for `test_remote`.